# Generate an unique ID in Appmaker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I want to assign automatically an unique ID to each record in Appmaker, but I don't really know how can I do it.

[image]

[image]

I thought that the "Auto increment" option would solve it, but not.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope this helps! (Click the image to enlarge it)

[image]